# Right to Left braces direction issue, angualrjs

Tags: angularjs

I try to solve language problem with braces.

I have a table and I populate `td`s like:

```
<td>{{item.biz_name + ' \(' + item.id + '\)'}}</td>
```

where `biz_name` might be in Hebrew or English.

By default I have style `direction: rtl;` for all table rows. If I'll change to `ltr` I get the results vise versa.

I found some info [HERE](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/align.html) but it doesn't help me a lot.

The solution is to change style (`ng-style`) for specific `td` that contains English chars.

So it should be some `if` statement: if Eng => set style `ltr` otherwise `rtl`.

How can I achieve that with angular?

Thanks,

Here is a <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/943/)</kbd> (see row 19)

[image]

**[EDIT]**

It works well in IE9-10 but not in Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular.

This has to do with the fact that parens (and brackets too) do not have an inherent "direction". Therefor when the browser goes to render your text RTL, it doesn't know the direction of the first paren it runs into on the other side, since it's not surrounded by directional characters (word characters), so it jumps it to the other side and "mirrors" it (flips it).

So, you need to let the browser know that your ) has a direction... You can do so two ways:

1. Use the LRM character in HTML:

   ```
   <div style="direction:rtl">Some Value (test)&#x200E;</div>
   ```
2. Use CSS styling:

   ```
   <style>
   .left-to-right-marked:after {
      content: "\200E";
   }
   </style>
   <div style="direction:rtl">
      <span class="left-to-right-marked">Some Value (test)</span>
   </div>
   ```

Either one will do.

[Here is an updated Fiddle, that's working with the ‎ fix](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsaCz/1/)

---

**EDIT**: On an Angular note, I'd recommend using `ng-bind="myValue"` over `{{myValue}}`, if for no other reason than to prevent "load flicker" that can occur while the user is waiting for module to bootstrap.

Comment: interesting, the question is why? parenthesis (and brackets too) do not have an inherent "direction", despite it clearly says "rtl" in css?

Answer (score 1):

I don' know how this css `direction` attribute works exactly, nor do I know anything about Hebrew, but I think this should help.
I added an ng-class to the relevant `td` element.

```
<td ng-class="{hebrew: !english(item.biz_name)}">{{item.biz_name + ' \(' + item.id + '\)'}}</td>
```

And I added the following function to the scope:

```
$scope.english = function(string) {
    return string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/);
};
```

This applies the hebrew class for all `item.biz_name` values which contain non-latin characters.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the direction from your text using filter

```
fessmodule.filter('direction', function () {
  return function (text) {
    return text.match(/^[a-z]/i) ? 'ltr' : 'inherit'; 
  }
});
```

Second, use that filter to ng-style

```
<td ng-style="{direction:(item.biz_name|direction)}" ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/945/